# How to create a list of matrices in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix

```
dim(mymat1)
[1] 171 173
dim(mymat2)
[1] 439 441
raw=list(mymat1, mymat2)
raw[1][,1:2]
```

> Error in list[1][, 1:2] : incorrect number of dimensions #I get an error

```
mymat1[,1:2] # no error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `raw[[1]]` rather than `raw[1]`.  See `?"["` for the technical details: `raw[1]` returns a **1-element list**, while `raw[[1]]` returns the **first element of the list**.